# (CSS) Table element overlaps and hides map area

Tags: css, image, html-table, area, overlapping

I have a div (which has `position: relative;`) and it contains 3 child element.
The first child element is an `image` ,the second child element is an `image-map` for the above image (and the map has 2 area fields which have links) which work when hovered over the image  and the third child element is a `table` (which overlaps the entire image {on purpose}) and is `position: absolute; top: 0;` naturally. (also the `table`  has 3 `<tr>` elements)

Problem is as follows: because the table element overlaps the entire image,it also overlaps the `map area's` and they can't be triggered by `hover` (*so when you hover over the image where the area maps are ,nothing happens,because the table is over them)*.

It looks something like this :

```
<div class="some class">
  <img class="some class" src="/image.png" use="mapname"/>
  <map name="random map name">
    <area href="some link" shape="rect" coords="some numbers">
    <area href="some link" shape="rect"coords="some numbers">
  </map>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td></tr>
    <tr><td></tr>
    <tr><td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can force the map areas to work?

IMPORTANT! : absolutely no changes to the DOM tree can be made,entire code is generated and has been made to work responsively. [So only CSS implementation can be made].

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: `<td>` require `</td>`.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Has anything here helped with the problem?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento that goes without saying.I just forgot to write it down.
-Askanison4 No it has not.
-JeevanJose I would have to type everything out,sadly i do not have that kind of time on my hands.I would copy paste,but like i said,the entire code is generated from the backend,it's not in any file.

Comment: Give an online example of the problem using the jsfindle

Answer (score 0):

Would setting a z-index on the table help you?

Your css could look like:

```
.some_class table {
   z-index: -1000;
}
```

Alternatively, if the table cells line up properly with your image map, could you put the overlay/hover events on the table also?

Comment: No it would not.
Because if you do that,then the image will be on top and hide the Table element.(the table is filled with text ,i forgot to mention this).

Comment: In that case you need to put your hover events onto the table instead of the image. Without Javascript you can't bubble the events up from underneath so that the CSS selectors get activated.